# Passing Object reference in Visual Basic (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

How do I pass a form's `TextBox` object to the a method?

The following code is issuing an exception.

```
Private Sub DoSmthWithTextBox(ByRef txtBox as TextBox)
    txtBox.BackColor = vbRed
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    DoSmthWithTextBox Me.TextBox1
End Sub
```

The problem appears when `DoSmthWithTextBox Me.TextBox1` passes the `String` from `TextBox1` instead of the object reference.

How do I pass the `TextBox` object to the `DoSmthWithTextBox` method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rewrite for Excel:

```
Private Sub DoSmthWithTextBox(txtBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    txtBox.BackColor = vbRed
End Sub
```

As far as I know, this is because Excel has an object textbox that is a shape, whereas  userforms use the ActiveX control textbox, so you need an explicit reference to the MSForms library.

Comment: +1 for knowing the difference. ;-) Can you write a short explanation?